# Как открыть доступ сервиса docs.google.com, к папке на сервере?

Tags: .htaccess, apache

Как открыть доступ сервиса **docs.google.com**, к папке на сервере?

**.htaccess**

```
Options -Indexes
Deny from all
Allow from <docs.google.com>
```

Так не работает...

Дело в том, что **docs.google.com** скорее всего использует **cdn**, и соответственно IP адреса могут меняться. Как правильно открыть доступ к папке с сервиса **docs.google.com**?

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под открыть доступ сервиса docs.google.com, к папке на сервере? может вы имели ввиду как на своем сайте прочитать любой документ из docs.google.com ?

Comment: @Lesyuk Alexey Не. Мне нужно чтобы docs.google.com мог прочитать файлы из папки на сервере, а для всех остальных чтобы был закрыт доступ к этой папке.  Я через фрейм HTML читаю файл. А фрейм читает из docs.google.com, а docs.google.com находит файл по ссылке, которая указывает на ту папку, которая должна быть закрыта для все кроме гуглдока, и где лежат документы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых. У Гугл нет четкого описания с каких серверов они будут ходить к Вам.
Тем более что эти адреса могут меняться.
Установить подсеть так же не поможет.

Во-вторых. Не только гугл докс к Вам сможет ходить за файлами.
Не исключено что поисковой робот проиндексирует файл и он окажется в открытом доступе. И будет доступен очень просто. Здесь никакой безопасности.

Попробуйте использовать гугл диск под эти задачи.

Для этого есть достаточно клиентов к гугл диску.
Для линукс, к примеру [вот](http://rus-linux.net/MyLDP/file-sys/grive.html) ( не пользовался сам.. но предполагаю что проблем не будет )

Если на сервере есть GUI, то и проблем вообще нет [официальный пакет](https://www.google.com/intl/ru_ru/drive/download/) все решит.